# Shopify Order API PayPal Gateway

Tags: php, paypal, shopify

I'm creating Orders via Shopify Order API with PHP. The Order itself is created successfully. But i can't set the "process_method" for the Gateway.

My target is to use PayPal Express. This is necessary because i'm using an customized Checkout for an Mobile App.

This i the Call Array

```
Array
(
    [order] => Array
        (
            [transactions] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [gateway] => paypal
                            [kind] => authorization
                            [authorization] => ##paypal-authorization-code##
                            [amount] => 0.01
                        )

                )

            [financial_status] => authorized
            [payment_gateway_names] => Array
                (
                    [0] => paypal
                )
            [processing_method] => express

            [email] => xxxxxxxx
            [line_items] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [variant_id] => 8101197938790
                            [quantity] => 1
                        )

                )

            [shipping_address] => Array
                (
                    [first_name] => Name
                    [last_name] => LastName
                    [address1] => Straße 1
                    [city] => Berlin
                    [country_code] => DE
                    [phone] => xxxxxxx
                    [zip] => 10000
                )

        )

)
```

This is the Response (shortened)
The "processing_method" is not set.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [order] => stdClass Object
        (
            ...

            [payment_gateway_names] => Array
                (
                    [0] => paypal
                )

            [processing_method] =>

            ...

        )

)
```

How to set "processing_method" in my case?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set a payment gateway when you create your own orders like that. Shopify only transacts orders with the checkout itself. You can assign amounts, and of course the source of the order is your App, but you cannot run payments through Paypal or any other credit processor with the Order API endpoint.

Comment: Hello David, thanks for your Answer. When you say "...like that", do you mean it is possible. If so, could you maybe give me an hint which API therefor could be used

Comment: No. It is not possible. Making up orders means you cannot transact them. They are real but never hit a gateway.